# Attach Header File To Target On Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, header, xcode-project, build-target

Im writing an Xcode project, and I want to have to different targets in the project.

The difference between the targets is that in one of my .c files I include

```
      #include "header_file.h"
```

I want to write two different "header_file.h"'s and to attach one to each target.

How can I do that?